# Magento 2 admin grids are not loading because of getting error in knockout.js

Tags: admin, grid, magento-2.1

I have installed new `Magento 2.1` its installed successfully.

Frontend is working fine, backend also loading able able to login.

Whenever i going to `Admin->Product->Catalog` grid is not loading even any grids in admin is not loading like `Order Grid`, `Customer Grid` are not loading i have checked console and seen below mentioned error.

```
knockout.js:2908 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

I have removed all caching and static data from command line and again run magento admin but its still getting same error.

You help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is not only with your Magento store cache. You can fix this issue by clearing all cookies, cache, browser history and saved information about your Magento store in your browser. If you want to know that these are things that are causing this problem. Just open the site in incognito mode in your browser. You will find it working fine without any problem.

Comment: I have checked in incognition mode check screen shot http://www.amanweb.in/stackexchange/errknockout.jpg